# Does 'r.patch' act only on "loaded" rasters?

Tags: raster, r, grass-gis

Can I run the GRASS command 'r.patch' on raster files which are not "loaded" into the current GRASS session? That is, rasters which are simply in my folder but not in a GRASS location & mapset?

Answer (score 1):

No, to work with raster files in GRASS you have to import the rasters with [r.in.gdal](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.in.gdal.html) or you can link external raster files with [r.external](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.external.html):

```
r.external input=/path/to/raster1.tif output=raster1
r.external input=/path/to/raster2.tif output=raster2
g.region rast=raster1,raster2 -p
r.patch input=raster1,raster2 output=raster_patched
```

Comment: Edit: I have added the g.region command to set the computational region (http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region) correctly prior to the patching.